# Citation for Gamma Probability Density Function?

Tags: gamma-distribution

Wondering if anyone has a reference for the Gamma PDF? I cannot find any leads.

Thanks

Comment: [NIST Engr Hdbk](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366b.htm). There are two common parameterizations of gamma distributions, this reference use 'shape' and 'scale' parameters. See the Wikipedia article on 'gamma distribution' to see discussion the other parameterization (using 'shape' and 'scale' parametrs) side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Gamma Distribution, Eq. (7.3.22) in CRC Standard Mathematical Tables, Editor DANIEL ZWILLINGER, 31th ed. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press, 2003.